# Looping through columns then rows to change certain numbers to zeroes, conditional on length of variable per column

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBbBf.png)I need to loop through 565 columns of data, each containing numbers that pertain to a category or amount, and the variables are different lengths, i.e. one column contains 0-9, with 6 through 9 being categorical and 0-5 being amounts, adjacent column contains 0-999, with 996,997,998, and 999 being categories (no account, closed account, etc.) and only 0-992 being age in months. I need to change any 'categorical' number to a zero, leaving only 'values'.

I have tried looping through columns and rows, checking the max length of the variables in a column to determine what 'category' it is in, then changing anything that is a 'category' number to 0. However, when I run the following, it does not change my data at all. I would also like to be able to append a column next to each column indicating the variable category, but that is commented out for now.

splitcode <- function(data){

```
    for ( i in ncol(data)){
      col <- data[,i]
      max_length <- max(nchar(col))

      for ( j in nrow(data)){
        val <- data[j,i]

          if( max_length == 1){
            ifelse(val > 5, 0,val)
            }
            #data$attribute_type[i] <- 'Amount'

          if( max_length == 2){
            ifelse(val > 92, 0, val)
            }
            #data$attribute_type[i] <- 'Number of Accounts'

          if( max_length == 3){
            ifelse(val > 992, 0, val)
          }
            #data$attribute_type[i] <- 'Age in Months'

          if(  max_length == 4){
            ifelse(val > 9992, 0, val)
          }
             #data$attribute_type[i] <- 'Age in Months'

          if(  max_length == 7){
            ifelse( val > 9999992, 0, val)
            #data$attribute_type[i] <- 'Total Balance'
          }

          else{
            #then we know you're a percentage
            ifelse(val > 1, 0, val)
            #data$attribute_type[i] <- 'Percentage'
          }
        }
    }
    return(data)
  }
```

I am getting no error messages, but the data returned is either null or unchanged. I want the data set returned to be the updated 0 values

Comment: Could you provide an excerpt of your data? Maybe with dput.

Comment: @TimTeaFan I added an  image to the description

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Since you only provide a picture of your data, it is hard for others to see, what is really going on. But, given that the data you are working with are real numbers (doubles and or integers and not factors or characters), then your code will work - the only thing you need to do is assign it to an object, for example a data.frame.

You loop over your data, but you are doing nothing with the output. For example instead of writing `ifelse(val > 1, 0, val)` you could write 
`data[j,i] <- ifelse(data[j,i] > 1, 0, data[j,i])`. Important here is the assignment operator `<-`.

However, changing your data in this way is not very R-like. Usually, it is enough to only work on columns, when using vectorized functions such as `ifelse`.

Below is a dplyr solution to your problem.

```
# load the package
library("dplyr")

# some test data, a column with max(nchar(x)==2
test_tbl <- tibble( a = c(0,0,1,99,3,4,99))


test_tbl <- test_tbl %>% # overwrite test data the following way
               # mutate (change) a column, if it has max 2 charaters
               mutate_if(~ max(nchar(.x))==2, 
               # sql-like case_when corresponds to your ifelse-statements
                         ~ case_when(.x > 92 ~ 0, 
                                     TRUE    ~ .x) 
                        ) # closes mutate_if
```

Hope this works for your data!